# How can I get a comment ID on Submit?

Tags: posts, comments, attachments

I've added an attachment field to my comment form. It stores the files on Amazon AWS and writes the URL, user ID, post ID, and a few other things to a custom table. I'm having some difficulty getting the comment ID in order to properly associate the attachment with the comment. Is there a good way to get the comment ID as it is being written?

I've looked over the documentation and cant seem to find anything that would get my comment ID on submit.

Comment: You can use the [`wp_insert_comment`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_insert_comment) hook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hook `comment_post` and add your logic with the comment id

```
// Save the data along with comment id
add_action( 'comment_post', 'wti_save_comment_data' );

function wti_save_comment_data( $comment_id ) {
    // Use the comment id and add your logic
}
```

Comment: I've got to rework some of my attachment script but this was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!